# Historical precursor for Peano's axioms of a linear space?

Tags: ho.history-overview, vector-spaces

Peano is typically credited with giving the first abstract definition of a vector space (1888):

http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/Abstract_linear_spaces.html

Apparently, Peano credits Möbius, Grassmann, and Hamilton for inspiring the idea. However, I  recall reading somewhere that there was an earlier and independent definition, not mentioned by Peano. (Maybe it was Dedekind?)

Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment:   
@Drew: I usually use the html characters &auml; (ä), &euml; (ë), &iuml; (ï), &ouml; (ö), &uuml; (ü) for umlauts. These will work in questions and answers, but apparently not in comments. Alternatively, you can just input ä, ë, ï, ö, ü directly (if you are able to input those; otherwise, you can copy and paste from somewhere else), and that should work in questions, answers, and comments on mathoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before Peano (1888), a more limited notion of vector space over the reals was axiomatized by 
Gaston Darboux (1875), in
*[Sur la composition des forces en statiques](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMA/BSMA_1875__9_/BSMA_1875__9__281_1/BSMA_1875__9__281_1.pdf)*.

This early history is discussed by Gregory Moore, [The axiomatization of linear algebra: 1875-1940](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/hmat.1995.1025)

> An earlier approach to axiomatizing
>   vectors emerged from the work of
>   Gaston Darboux. In 1875 he published
>   an article analyzing various proofs of
>   the composition of forces in statics
>   (i.e., the parallelogram law),
>   beginning with one due to Daniel
>   Bernoulli in 1726. Darboux set himself
>   the task of treating this matter in
>   pure geometry and then determining
>   which assumptions are necessary.

Comment: Very interesting. I would be curious then to learn what is Darboux' "more limited notion".
 

Comment: @Carlos: Thanks. That paper of Gregory Moore is extremely helpful.

Comment: P.S. I believe I was mistakenly thinking of Weyl's (1918) <b>re-discovery</b> when I asked the question. I still don't remember where I read about it...